# Send variable from one jdbc request to another jdbc request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

In my test plan I have 3 JDBC connection request, from second request's response I want pass the variable to 3rd request, I tried with `escape character` and `vars.get`,

2nd Request for fetching `group-transaction-id`

[image]

3rd Request for fetching `details` using the `group-transaction-id`
[image]

Tried with :

```
SELECT DISTINCT L.audit_context_key,K.event_log_value,L.event_log_id,L.event_logged_dttm FROM event_log L,event_log_keys K
WHERE L.audit_context_key LIKE 'vars.get('GROUP_TRANSID_1')%'
AND L.event_process='Interfaces/GenericPublishingService/StarterProcesses/GPFAdapterSubscriber.process'
```

also with

```
SELECT DISTINCT L.audit_context_key,K.event_log_value,L.event_log_id,L.event_logged_dttm FROM event_log L,event_log_keys K
WHERE L.audit_context_key LIKE '''vars.get('''GROUP_TRANSID_1''')%'''
AND L.event_process='Interfaces/GenericPublishingService/StarterProcesses/GPFAdapterSubscriber.process'
```

nothing is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have your answer in your question,

first `vars.get` is scripting element which you cannot use in a query and second `escape character` will not work. So you need to pass it as parameter like in Jmeter,

```
SELECT DISTINCT L.audit_context_key,K.event_log_value,L.event_log_id,L.event_logged_dttm FROM event_log L,event_log_keys K
WHERE L.audit_context_key LIKE '${GROUP_TRANSID_1}%'
```

or if you really want to use `vars.get` then please use the following,

```
SELECT DISTINCT L.audit_context_key,K.event_log_value,L.event_log_id,L.event_logged_dttm FROM event_log L,event_log_keys K
    WHERE L.audit_context_key LIKE '${__groovy(vars.get('GROUP_TRANSID_1'),)}%'
```